# MFC ODBC Stored Procedure Parameters with Unicode Characters

Tags: stored-procedures, unicode, mfc, odbc

The Stored Procedure is like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertItemsSPRoc] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@File_Name nvarchar(400) =  NULL,   -- file name to be inserted
@Path_File_Name nvarchar(400) = NULL,   -- path file name to be inserted

    -- insert in the Media_Files FILETABLE
    -- set the specific table holder
    set @sql = N'insert into Media_Files (name, file_stream) (SELECT ''' + @File_Name + ''', * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N''' + @Path_File_Name + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS FileData)'

    -- execute the combined statement
    exec(@sql)
```

The Stored Procedure is called through a MFC statement and is executing nicely when the passing parameters are ANSI, i.e. English letters. The problem arises when the user selects a file with file name made up of Unicode letters like "Ένα Δείγμα.mp4" (definitely looks Greeks to me) where the exemption I get is like below:

> Cannot bulk load because the file "D:??? ??????.mp4" could not be opened. Operating system error code 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.).

Apparently the ODBC driver is passing gibberish or something.

I have tried to debug/execute the same stored procedure using the same parameters using MSSM Studio and there is no problem.

How can I pass parameters in a stored procedure?

Comment: You haven't said whether your MFC application is built with Unicode or not. Does the system you're calling expect the filename as encoded with Greek or does it accept Unicode or does it accept UTF-8?

Comment: MFC Application is built with Unicode. Additionally SQL Server 2016 database is using nvarchar all the way, and execution of the Stored Procedure from within the MSSM environment with Greeks, is without any flaw.

Comment: The ? question marks in the filename is what usually happens when converting from Unicode to "Ansi" (in quotes, because really the system char set)  when using the WIndows API function WideCharToMultiByte() and it can't convert the character. IDK how to help.

Comment: Just a thought, is that N marker after the `BULK` keyword really needed there? I think it should best go just before the `''', * FROM OPENROWSET(` clause. That is, I would rather try `@File_Name + N''', * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @Path_File_Name...`. (`@Path_File_Name` IS `nvarchar`). Better do a simple test, insert the `@sql` text into a `nvarchar` field of a a test-table and check what exactly goes in there. Also, is `@sql` `nvarchar`?

Comment: After moving around the N and testing have nada again. inserting @sql in a nvarchar gives me ??? again. Think is the setup of the ODBC. Debugging line by line takes me to dbcore.cpp line 336 where a call to   AFX_ODBC_CALL(::SQLExecDirect(hstmt, reinterpret_cast<SQLTCHAR *>(pszSQL), SQL_NTS));
 is made. I think that the call should be made to SQLExecDirectW, but I don't know how to link the Sqlucode.h in my stdafx.h file

Comment: @sql is nvarchar()

Comment: Checked the include files, and found that just like many Win32 types and functions,`SQLExecDirect()` is a macro, defined either as `SQLExecDirectA()` or `SQLExecDirectW()`, depending on the project settings. And `SQLTCHAR` is defined as either `SQLWCHAR` or `SQLCHAR` (those `T` defines). If you right-click on `SQLExecDirect()`and select "Go to Definition" you can see which one is actually called. Maybe an implicit conversion using the default or some hard-coded codepage. Also check your project to check if everything (compiler, settings, defines, libraries etc) is indeed Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

It was the code page of the database. When I changed, painfully indeed as there were a lot lot lot of dependencies among the tables, to Collation

> SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AS

, the Microsoft specific for Greeks, the problem was solved, and the Greek characters where recognized when were received through the MFC call stored Procedure

Comment: This won't cover all cases though, if you wish to be able to store characters in other languages as well, eg accented characters in the Western (1252) or Eastern (1250) codepages. You need a nchar/nvarchar2 field there. For testing, try mixing characters of different codepages in the same string, eg Hœrdt-Łódź-Αθήνα.

Comment: @Constantine, THANKS a lot for your comment. The problem is not the fields in the database, as all of them are nvarchar ONLY. The application is working on clients having Greeks and US/UK keyboard, so there is a big chance for a client to choose a file with Greek name, and there is the problem. ODBC uses UCS-2 which is something like UTF-16 which Microsoft doesn't like for space reasons. The problem was solved by changing the code page and it would be the perfect solution to switch to the codepage that translates best ALL the Unicode characters. Please provide and will delete this one.